# Can't format or erase flash card neither on Linux nor on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, micro-sd-card, memory-card, card-reader

I have brand new flash memory card (MicroSD), which I am connecting to the computer via relatively old, but USB3 card readers. I've tried two different card readers.  One card reader says card "is write protected" and the other appears to delete the file, but it does not.  Once each file is deleted the entire Windows GUI is redrawn.

What is it?

Can it be an effect of old card reader or corrupted card?

Comment: "Brand new"? Return or get a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Some cards have a switch on them which write protect the card to avoid accidentally destroying the contents.  For the MicroSD see [here](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6971/~/sandisk-microsd-memory-card-is-write-protected-or-locked)

> SOLUTION 1 - Unlock the memory card
>
> If you are using a microSD to SD adapter, make sure the Lock switch on
>   the left side of the adapter card is slid up (unlock position).
>
> You will NOT be able to modify or delete the contents on the memory
>   card if it is locked.
>
> SOLUTION 2 - Toggle the lock switch.
>
> If the lock switch is loose and moves easily It is likely the switch
>   is sliding to the locked position as the card is placed in your host
>   device. In this case the card will need to be replaced.
>
> Please contact SanDisk support to check warranty status.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem you describe in the past and it was actually because of a corrupted card.  Not sure why Windows will think it is deleting the files but I saw the delete animation also, but then the files aren't deleted.

My SD card had been corrupted because a Kindle Fire had written to it millions of times due to a bug.